# What's the root cause of error "Failed dependencies: /bin/sh is needed by xxx" on RHEL?

Tags: sh, rpm, rhel

When I install a rpm package on RHEL using rpm, I got a error message just like "Failed dependencies: /bin/sh is needed by xxx".

I checked that /bin/sh is there and it links to /bin/bash and bash works well.

I found a solution that to add `--nodeps` to the rpm command to solve this problem. But I really want to know what is the root cause?

Comment: You should make your comment an answer then mark that answer as correct.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to make my comment as an correct answer?

Comment: There should be a button below my answer that allows you to add an answer. Once you've added an answer, then just click the check mark to the left of the answer you created.

Comment: OK. I deleted my comment, then post it as a answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have find root cause for this problem. The rpm-libs is missing on my machine. I reinstall rpm-libs then everything is ok. Note: After installing rpm-libs, if the problem still exists, please try "rpm -v --rebuilddb --define="_rpmlock_path /var/lock/rpm"".

Answer (score 11):

**How to reproduce this error on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.**

1. Fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04
2. Do a `sudo apt-get install rpm`
3. download the nomachine rpm 64 bit linux from https://www.nomachine.com/download/download&id=4
4. Do a `chmod +x nomachine_4.2.25_1_x86_64.rpm` on it
5. extract it like this:

   ```
   el@apollo:~Desktop$ sudo rpm -i nomachine_4.2.25_1_x86_64.rpm
   rpm:  RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
   rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
   error: Failed dependencies:
   /bin/sh is needed by nomachine-4.2.25-1.x86_64
   ```
6. So that is the error.  To fix it I followed its advice to use alien.

   ```
   sudo alien -i nomachine_4.2.25_1_x86_64.rpm --scripts
   ```

And no machine installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

seems to me as though there is most likely a problem with your RPM database. Have you removed or modified it in any way lately? I'd start with the [Fedora documentation](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch04s05s02.html) that explains how to rebuild the database.

Comment: Before I used the "--nodeps" to solve this problem, I have tried using "rpm --rebuilddb", but it does not work.